# Get aweber subscriber between date range or for specifc day

Tags: php, aweber

I am fetching subscribers from aweber using PHP API. I am able to fetch all subscriber or from specific list. Following code, I am using

```
try {
$params = array('status' => 'subscribed');
$found_subscribers = $account->findSubscribers($params);
foreach($found_subscribers as $subscriber) {
    echo $subscriber->email . "\n";     
}
} catch(AWeberAPIException $exc) {
print "<h3>AWeberAPIException:</h3>";
print " <li> Type: $exc->type              <br>";
print " <li> Msg : $exc->message           <br>";
print " <li> Docs: $exc->documentation_url <br>";
print "<hr>";
}
```

My question is, is there any way so that I can get records between specific date range? Current I know only following search parameter

```
$params = array('status' => 'subscribed');
```

I have read documentation but could not find.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching by date range is not available unfortunately. I've had the same problem.

It would be easier for you to simply export all users to a mysql table since you do seem to know programming and then query your table by date range, which is possible.